# Hide ifdef(or gray out) through compile_command.json

Tags: lsp-mode, ccls

I've just finished to set up LSP with ccls and company packages.
It works but I have one more possible wish that such LSP packages could do.
Now I'm using hide-ifdef package to gray out the inactve code area but it reads preprocessors from my certain .dir-locals.el.
As you know, such preprocessors are already in compile_commands.json.
I wonder some of LSP package could do the same thing - ie graying out the inactive area. Or whether I have to write a new package to do so.
Please share your experience.

Answer (score 2):

old but it may help someones. You need to use lsp token highligthing by setting this variable:

```
lsp-semantic-tokens-enable
```

to `t`.